# Bitmap -> IplImage in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I would like to use IplImage and to perform some functions in the opencv in android.However, I just have a bitmap image.
How can I convert a bitmap to a IplImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load it with [cvLoadImage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvLoadImage).

Comment: since i need the data of each pixel , it will be better to convert to IPIImage

Comment: @Vivian `cvLoadImage` returns an `IPLImage`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/), there are a couple of hints on this page:

http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=67